# Backing into subpage anchors in overflowed content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML page with links to subsections in a content wrapper that is positioned/sized and uses `overflow:auto` to show a scrollbar. Links to the subsections work (cause the content to scroll to the correct height) but **using the Back button does not re-scroll to the correct section** in Firefox v13, IE v9, or Opera v11 (it does work in Chrome v20 and Safari v5).

Given that I cannot *drastically* change my CSS (I need to use a positioned, sized, overflowing content) how can I work around this problem?

*Solutions involving JavaScript/jQuery are acceptable, but a plain CSS fix is preferable.*

### Test Page: [phrogz.net/tmp/backing…containers.html](http://phrogz.net/tmp/backing-into-subpage-anchors-in-overflowed-containers.html)

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Backing into Subpage Anchors in Overflowed Containers</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    #site-nav { position:fixed; width:10em; top:0; left:0 }
    #contents { position:fixed; top:3em; bottom:5em; left:11em; right:0;
                overflow:auto; background:#fed }
    div            { height:15em }
    div:last-child { height:55em }
  </style>
</head><body>

<article id="contents">
  <div>
    <h1 id="a">Section A</h1>
    <p>Navigate to the different sections at left, and then press the Back button.</p>
  </div>
  <div><h1 id="b">Section B</h1></div>
  <div><h1 id="c">Section C</h1></div>
</article>
<ul id="site-nav">
  <li><a href="#a">Section A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#b">Section B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#c">Section C</a><ul>
</ul>

</body></html>
```

Previously-filed Firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=391664
Referenced as Opera Bug: DSK-365451@bugs.opera.com

Comment: Note that removing `position:fixed; overflow:auto` from the contents _does_ fix the problem for all browsers, so the 'bug' is directly related to that markup (which I require).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use onhashchange event. It's supported only by newer broswers, but plug-ins are available, for example http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

When hash changes, you can find element by ID and change container's scrollTop attribute. Something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).hashchange(function(){
        var elem = $(location.hash);
        if (elem.count() > 0) {
            elem.offsetParent().animate({scrollTop: elem.position().top});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You get the acceptance for linking to the right polyfill library for hashchange. I fixed some of your code to work. See my answer for a more robust way to find the correct scroll top when the sub-item may be positioned.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this using jQuery, the [hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) suggested by @barius, and the following code:

```
jQuery(function($){
  var $content = $('#contents');
  $(window).hashchange(scrollHashIntoView);

  function scrollHashIntoView(){
    // Ensure that the ID I'm looking for is within my scrolling content
    var offset = $content.find(location.hash).offsetRelativeTo($content);
    $content.scrollTop( offset ? offset.top : 0 );
  }
});

// Find the offset of an element relative to some ancestor
jQuery.fn.offsetRelativeTo = function(el){
  var $el=$(el), o=this.offset(), o2=$el.offset();
  if (o){
    o.top  -= o2.top  - $el.scrollTop();
    o.left -= o2.left - $el.scrollLeft();
  }
  return o;
}
```

The `offsetRelativeTo()` code was necessary for my more complex case when one of the sub-anchors happened to be inside a `position:relative` parent (that was itself inside the scrolling content).

I made `scrollHashIntoView()` a separate function because (a) it helps to self-document the behavior, and (b) it allows me to invoke it separately when needed, and (c) it separates the implementation of the work away from the terse event registration and their actions.

A more robust solution (handling the unlikely-but-possible case of nested scrolling regions) would find the id and walk up the tree of `offsetParent`s, scrolling each into view as appropriate.

Answer (score -1):

I was also going to recommend the `onhashchange` event but it is not supported by older browsers.  A simple solution is to simply use the hash of the first anchor on your page and automatically set it to that if you do not have a hash.

```
$(function() {
    if(window.location.hash == '') {
        window.location.hash = $("a[href^='#']:first").attr('href');
    }
});
```

Comment: What you're suggesting would--on page load--change the hash to the first anchor on the page, but never fix the explicit problem of the Back.